# Having a middleware function before express.static doesnt work

Tags: node.js, express

I am running the latest express (4.1.1 as of writing). It has this [middleware](https://www.npmjs.org/package/serve-static) included to serve static files.

So the usual code to include this middleware is:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

And great that all works fine. But if I try to include a middleware before that, eg:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){                    
    next();                                          
}, express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

The serve-static middleware now gives me 404s.

I am not sure why this is happening. Did I implement the middleware that goes before the static middleware incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of [`app.use()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use) is incorrect. From the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use):

> **`app.use([path], function)`**
>   Use the given middleware `function`, with optional mount `path`, defaulting to "/".

You will notice that `app.use` accepts an optional path and a function, not multiple functions. Therefore, you should be defining each middleware with its own `app.use` call, as seen below:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){                    
    next();                                          
});
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```