# Using middleware with express().use along with express.static

Tags: node.js, express, static, middleware

I'm using PassportJS to secure a WebApp (written with AngularJS). I'm using NodeJS with Express (4.0.0) to serve static content after the login-screen. I don't get how to use a middleware along with `express.static()` at the same time.

My (not working) code looks like

```
app.use('/secure', 
    function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated())
            return next();

        res.redirect('/');
    }, 
    express.static(__dirname + '/../../client'));
```

The plan is, that the middleware ensures, that the user is only forwareded to the WebApp if he/she is logged in. If not, he/she/it is redirected to the root folder.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457127/having-a-middleware-function-before-express-static-doesnt-work), but according to [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use), the new version supports multiple functions. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473399/using-express-static-middleware-in-an-authorized-route) isn't the "clean" solution I'm looking for, since the directory contains too many subfolders and files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand how that other question/answer doesn't solve your situation. It seems like an exact match... what am I missing?

Comment: What version of Express do you have installed?

Comment: I'm using "version": "4.0.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attach middlewares to the same route they get executed in the same order of declaration, so if you want to execute any middleware before `express.static`, all what you have to do is attach it to the same route and declare it before.

```
app.use('/secure', myMiddleWare);
app.use('/secure', express.static(__dirname + '/../../client'));
```